# how to inceament date

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [read line using java & maped filterd data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536572/read-line-using-java-maped-filterd-data)

- i hav below text file

11/2/2010,cat,6
11/2/2010,cat,3
11/2/2010,dog,4
11/2/2010,cat,11
11/3/2010,cat,1
11/3/2010,dog,3
11/3/2010,cat,8
11/3/2010,cat,80

- in my java code it is filtered below output.
  11/2/2010    cat    20    3
  11/3/2010    cat    104    4
  11/4/2010    cat    26    2
- But i want below mention result.
  11/01/2010
  11/02/2010    cat    20    3
  11/03/2010    cat    104    4
  11/04/2010    cat    26    2
  11/05/2010
  11/06/2010
  11/07/2010
  11/08/2010
  11/09/2010
  11/10/2010
  11/11/2010
  11/12/2010
  11/13/2010
  11/14/2010
  11/15/2010
  11/16/2010
  11/17/2010
  11/18/2010
  11/19/2010
  11/20/2010
  11/21/2010
  11/22/2010
  11/23/2010
  11/24/2010
  11/25/2010
  11/26/2010
  11/27/2010
  11/28/2010
  11/29/2010
  11/30/2010

here is my java code.....help me to solve this......

```
public class Reader {  
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {  
            BufferedReader reader;  
            String animalName=&quot;cat&quot;;  
            String animal = null;  
            try {  
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(  
                        new FileInputStream(&quot;C:/dila.txt&quot;)));  
                Map&lt;String, Integer&gt; result = new LinkedHashMap&lt;String, Integer&gt;();  
                Map&lt;String, Integer&gt; result2 = new LinkedHashMap&lt;String, Integer&gt;();  

                while (reader.ready()) {  
                    String line = reader.readLine();  
/*split a line with spaces*/  
                    String[] values = line.split(&quot;,&quot;);  
                    String key = null;                    
                    if(values[1].compareTo(animalName)==0){  
                    key = values[0];  
                    animal=&quot;&quot;+values[1].compareTo(animalName);  
                    int sum = 0;  
                    int count = 0;  
/*get a last counter and sum*/  
                    if (result.containsKey(key)) {  
                        sum = result.get(key);  
                        count = result2.get(key);  
                    } else{  
                    }  
 /*increment sum a count and save in the map with key*/  
                    result.put(key, sum + Integer.parseInt(values[2]));  
                    result2.put(key, count + 1);  
                }  
                }  

 /*interate and print new output*/  
                for (String key : result.keySet()) {  
                    Integer sum = result.get(key);  
                    Integer count = result2.get(key);  
                    System.out.println(key +&quot;   &quot;+animalName+ &quot; &quot; + sum + &quot;\t&quot; + count);  
                }  
                reader.close();  
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  

        }  
    }
```